# Python - How to check if all values in list are in a dataframe column?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'X':['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Year':[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2015, 2019, 2020, 2021]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And a list:

```
l = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]
```

I want to check if ALL the values in `l` appear in `data['Year']`.

E.g. it should return `False`, as 2022 does not appear in `data['Year']`

Every example I have found only looks for one value, which I would have to loop through e.g.

```
2022 in data["Year"].values
```

Is there a simplier (faster) way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `set.issubset`:

```
out = set(l).issubset(df['Year'])
```

Alternatively, you could use `all`:

```
out = all(y in df['Year'] for y in l)
```

Output:

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

```
res = set(l).issubset(df['Year'])
print(res)
# False
```